# Null error when dividing, but numerator and denominator runs fine when spilt up

Tags: sql, db2

This one probably has a really obvious answer but I cannot figure out why its erroring out:

```
(sum(case when N.DOS_DURATION <= 3 then N.NURA_Claims else 0 end)/sum(case when N.DOS_DURATION <= 3 then N.SRD_Prem else 0 end)) as NURA_MBR_Q1

ERROR [2:1]:(SQLSTATE: 42911, SQLCODE: -419): DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-419, SQLSTATE=42911, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.25.13
ERROR [2:1]:(SQLSTATE: 56098, SQLCODE: -727): DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-419;42911;, DRIVER=4.25.13
```

However, splitting up the numerator and denominator runs fine, and there’s no null or 0 values.

```
sum(case when N.DOS_DURATION <= 3 then N.NURA_Claims else 0 end) as Claims, 
sum(case when N.DOS_DURATION <= 3 then N.SRD_Prem else 0 end) as Premiums
```

I’m stumped! Any suggestions?
[numerator and denominator output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lq67W.jpg)

Comment: Have you read this? https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/error-sql0419n-decimal-divide-operation-not-valid-because-result-would-have-negative-scale-sqlstate42911

Comment: Your denominator code has a condition that has the potential to return zero (“else 0”). What do you want the overall calculation to return if N.DOS_DURATION > 3?

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to the rules described at the [Expressions](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=elements-expressions) link. Look at the `Decimal arithmetic in SQL` topic and the `Table 4. Precision and scale of the result of a decimal division` table.
You may resolve the problem either with the [dec_arithmetic](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=parameters-dec-arithmetic-decimal-arithmetic-mode) database configuration parameter or with data type casting.
Below is an example, when `dec_arithmetic` is set to its default value.

```
SELECT
  -- Wrong - negative precision:
  -- 31 - p + s - s' = 31 - 31 + 2 - 3 = -1
  -- You get the same error as in the question.
  --NURA_Claims / SRD_Prem

  -- Correct - we achieve the desired precision with 
  -- data type casting for one of the operands
  -- 31 - p + s - s' = 31 - 31 + 5 - 3 = 2
  DEC (NURA_Claims, 31, 5) / SRD_Prem
FROM (VALUES (DEC (2, 31, 2), DEC (1, 31, 3))) N (NURA_Claims, SRD_Prem)
```